# Which java program makes the hadoop remote datanode block replication?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm quite new to hadoop, I need which java programs works for making replication on remote datanode.

For example if I'm executing this command 
bin/hadoop dfs -setrep -w 2 /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data1  which passes through FSShell.java but actual block replication is made somewhere else so whcih is that program Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This is handled by the [FileSystem.setReplication](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#setReplication%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20short%29) method, and can be called using code as follows:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(configuration);
fs.setReplication(new Path("/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data1"), 2);
```